# Generating an image from a LaTeX document

Tags: python, latex, wxpython

I have written a Python script that generates LaTeX output. I want to view the generated LaTeX as a 'document' within my wxPython application.

The only way I can think of doing this is to dynamically generate an image from the LaTeX string and then paint the image onto a StaticBitmap widget.

Something along these lines. Here, its Google's mathtext module which is used to parse the LaTex string - however, it is LaTeX lite and only works for math expressions. I want to be able to parse an entire LaTeX document and generate an image from it.

```
import wx
import mathtext

class LaTex:
    def __init__(self, rawText, pos = (0, 0), size = 72):
        self.laTexParser = mathtext.MathTextParser('Bitmap')
        self.rawText = rawText
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size
        self.setImage()

    def setImage(self):
        img = self.laTexParser.parse(self.rawText, self.size)
        img = wx.ImageFromData(img.get_width(), img.get_height(),
img.as_rgb_str())
        self.img = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)

    def draw(self, dc):
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.img, self.pos[0], self.pos[1])

s = get_latex_doc()
test = LaTex(s)
#test.draw(your_DC_here)
```

Is there a Python library/module I can use to parse a LaTeX document into an image (preferably, without having to save the image to file)?

Comment: LaTeX is so huge that I fear the only way is to just call `pdflatex` (or similar, whatever you need) and display its output. Do you control what packages are used by this document? If so, are there any which specifically depend on PDF or PS output (like `hyperref`, `pstricks`…)?

Comment: @lori: Yes, I control the packages used. I am not using any packages that depend on PDF or PS. Last but not the least, I suspected that  I will have to spawn something like pdflatex to do the heavy work - its just that I'm not sure how to use pdflatex to create an in memory image (i.e. without saving to file first).

Comment: Just save a file to `/tmp` and load it into your application. That's what that directory is there for.

Comment: What did you do eventually? Convert using ImageMagick the PDF file to an image?